# Codefirst MVC app interacting with PowerPoint error when accessing slides

Tags: ef-code-first, interop, initialization

I am creating an application which needs to generate a thumbnail and graphical representation of a ppt slide. The code of which does not look tricky:

```
pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(ppt, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
var filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".png";
var thumbPath = Path.Combine(root, "thumbs") + filename;
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in pptPresentation.Slides)
{
    slide.Export(thumbPath, "png", 160, 120);
}
```

The problem lies that with this code in the project (it doesn't even get to run) this code fails on application start. I have put an arrow by the line of code that fails.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseSeeder());
        MibContext ctx = new MibContext();
  -->   ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MibContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

The error is the dreaded : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.TryCreateStructuralType(Type type, StructuralType cspaceType, EdmType& newOSpaceType)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.TryCreateType(Type type, EdmType cspaceType, EdmType& newOSpaceType)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel.CreateObjectContext[TContext](DbConnection existingConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.MarkDatabaseInitialized()
at System.Data.Entity.Database.Initialize(Boolean force)
at Mib.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Projects\MiB\MiB\Mib\Global.asax.cs:line 25
```

If I comment out the foreach section (it is the foreach line causing the problem) then the application will run as expected.

```
pptPresentation.Slides[0]
```

will also fail.

The strange thing is that it is not getting to this, because the failure happens in the AppStart section. I have no idea what the link between these things are, or even where to start to resolve this.

Comment: It doesn't break if it uses var slide = ... but when there is code to cast it (even safely using "as" keyword) it breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out to be quite simple.

Don't have your own class called "Slide" in the project. Once renamed the conflict went away.